# Formula to count information of 2 different columns

Tags: count, sum, formula

I have a column A with various names of areas lets say Area 1 to 10 (repeated throughout the column, one in each cell). Then I have a column B with dates that something was done in that specific area, some cells no date is in yet because nothing was done. I need to create a summary where I count how many times that something was done in that specific area. That means I need to take each area (Area 1, area 2, area 3 etc.) and count how many times I did an action. I will know it was done by the fact that there is a date in column B. I need a formula that can help me calculate this.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(('Boiler Xray'!B:B="Primary Superheater Connecting Legs")+('Boiler Xray'!I:I,">1")) This is what I have tried.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you specify which database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

# create sample data
df <- tibble(A=rep(c(1:10),3), B=rep(c(Sys.Date(), NA),15))

df

       A B         
 1     1 2019-02-06
 2     2 NA        
 3     3 2019-02-06
 4     4 NA        
 5     5 2019-02-06
 6     6 NA        
 7     7 2019-02-06
 8     8 NA        
 9     9 2019-02-06
10    10 NA      
...

# grouping and summarising it for column A
df %>%
  mutate(count=ifelse(!is.na(B), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(count,na.rm=T))

       A count
 1     1     3
 2     2     0
 3     3     3
 4     4     0
 5     5     3
 6     6     0
 7     7     3
 8     8     0
 9     9     3
10    10     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well:

```
SELECT area_name, COUNT(action_date) WHERE action_date <> '' GROUP by area_name;
```